# Error during installation of gulp in node js

Tags: node.js, git, gulp

i am installing my package.json in node project. but it is showing errors on installation of gulp. in package.json gulp module is

- "gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0",

and it throws this error

- silly fetchPackageMetaData error for github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0 Command
  failed: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.EXE checkout 4.0
- silly fetchPackageMetaData error: pathspec '4.0' did not match any
  file(s) known to git.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your gulp dependency to:

```
"gulp": "4.0.0",
```

Should solve this issue.

*Edited to add longer explanation*: Take into account that, for Gulp version, you were referencing branch "4.0" of the Gulp project in GitHub. Such branch no longer exists, thus the error. My proposed solution is to use the same version (4.0.0), but from the NPM registry instead of from GitHub.